# Setting dtype in numpy seems to make each value become a tuple

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to set a dtype such that I can sort by one of the columns on of this array. s an example lets say I have a row `[1 2]` in my array. After seeing dtype it becomes `[(1,1),(2,2)]`  For example, this is the code I am trying to run.

```
print "original shape \n",b.shape
print 'original \n',b
typ = [('dist',float),('ys',float)]
p = np.array(b,dtype=typ)
print "new shape \n", p.shape
print "new \n",p
```

and this is the output

```
original shape 
(3, 2)
original 
[[ 10.29563014   1.        ]
 [  6.08276253   3.        ]
 [ 18.44670431   7.        ]]
new shape 
(3, 2)
new 
[[(10.295630140987, 10.295630140987) (1.0, 1.0)]
 [(6.082762530298219, 6.082762530298219) (3.0, 3.0)]
 [(18.44670431269499, 18.44670431269499) (7.0, 7.0)]]
```

Technically the shape doesn't change but I have no idea why it basically makes each entry in the tuple a duplicate of itself.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Reread the compound dtype documentation.  Pay attention to the display style of a structure array.

Comment: `astype` doesn't work because it is converting each element to the new dtype.  You expect it to convert each row (pairs of elements) to the new dtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting by 1st column without resorting to structured array:

```
In [507]: x=np.array([[10.29,1],[6.08,3],[18.44,7]])
In [508]: x
Out[508]: 
array([[ 10.29,   1.  ],
       [  6.08,   3.  ],
       [ 18.44,   7.  ]])
In [509]: ind=np.argsort(x[:,0])
In [510]: x[ind,:]
Out[510]: 
array([[  6.08,   3.  ],
       [ 10.29,   1.  ],
       [ 18.44,   7.  ]])
```

taking advantage of the `sort` `order` parameter, we can do

```
In [524]: np.sort(x.view('f8,f8'),order=['f0'],axis=0).view('f8')
Out[524]: 
array([[  6.08,   3.  ],
       [ 10.29,   1.  ],
       [ 18.44,   7.  ]])
```

I assume this later one is why you are trying to change the dtype.  Display with tuples is normal with structured arrays (the compound dtype).

As to the other answer noted, the `view` makes the structured array 2d.  Reshaping or squeeze can remove that extra dimension. But the return to a simple dtype works better if I leave it as is.  I assume this works with more columns, and maybe with more dimensions, but I haven't tested that.

The `argsort` approach is faster:

```
In [526]: timeit x[np.argsort(x[:,0]),:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.2 µs per loop
In [527]: timeit np.sort(x.view('f8,f8'),order=['f0'],axis=0).view('f8')
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.5 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do it casting each value of `b` to `typ`, so you duplicate each value.

What you need is too `view` them in a different way :

```
In [13]: b.view(typ)
Out[13]: 
array([[(10.29563014, 1.0)],
       [(6.08276253, 3.0)],
       [(18.44670431, 7.0)]], 
      dtype=[('dist', '<f8'), ('ys', '<f8')])
```

But its always a 2D array. to overcome this use `squeeze` :

```
In [14]: b.view(typ).squeeze()
Out[14]: 
array([(10.29563014, 1.0), (6.08276253, 3.0), (18.44670431, 7.0)], 
      dtype=[('dist', '<f8'), ('ys', '<f8')])
```